# Php pattern descriptions

Tags: php, design-patterns

What does code in PHP, such as

```
"/(?<!\..|\...|\....)([\?\!\.]+)\s(?!.\.|..\.|...\.)/u"
```

mean? I'm looking for general documentation, not to understand this specific case.

Thank you.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expression or Regex for friends.

- [POSIX Regex](http://php.net/manual/en/book.regex.php)
- [PCRE Regex](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php)
- [Differences between POSIX and PCRE Regex](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.posix.php)

Comment: @Randomblue, if this answer answers your question you should accept it as answer by clicking the "V" right above the answer votes count.

Answer (score 1):

Those are [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)